# Using generics in abstract classes

Tags: c#, generics, abstraction

I'm working on an abstract class where the implementing class needs to implement a list of T. The problem is that this doesn't work:

```
public class AbstractClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass
{
    public List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure that there is an obvious answer that I'm missing, and I know that I can build an abstract base type to put in the list, but when I use my Linq command to build the list, the abstract type (ItemBase) doesn't play nicely with the .ToList() method. Is what I'm trying to do so unique?

Comment: It turns out that I need to learn to research better. Apologies to all of the answers that were the same that didn't get the check mark. I chose the top one based off of it's completeness and the fact it was top.

Comment: Do you actually want `Items` to be abstract? (ie to override the get or set properties?)  If you extend from `AbstractClass<Widgets>` like most people are suggesting, `Container.Items` will implicitly be a `List<Widgets>`, and you won't even need to override it.

Comment: I want to leave the possibility of the getter and setter methods being overridden later on. In theory I don't need to, but in practice trying to undo that mess leads to a world of hurt.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need the declaration on the class as well, to know what type `T` is:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widgets>
{
    public override List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You can also restrict what T can be, like say it must implement `IWidgets`:

```
public class AbstractClass<T> where T : IWidgets
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `abstract` key word in the class declaration line itself, not just the property.

Answer (score 11):

- You need to declare the type T.
- You need to declare the class AbstractClass as abstract.
- You need to use the override keyword.

Try this:

```
public class Widgets { }

public abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widgets>
{
    public override List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to make `AbstractClass` generic

```
public class AbstractClass<T> {
  ...
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widgets> { ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to mark AbstractClass **`abstract`**, because it contains abstract property
2. Specify the **generic type** in the `AbstractClass` declaration
3. Implement abstract property with **`override`**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widgets>
{
    public override List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define T like so

```
public class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widget>
{
    public List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type in the abstract class:

```
public class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widgets>
{
    public List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to define abstract keyword for your AbstractClass class and also you need to add override keyword for Container Class Items property. I am giving the example code which will run for sure.

```
namespace AbstractGeneric
{

public abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public abstract List<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Widgets
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Container : AbstractClass<Widgets>
{
    public override List<Widgets> Items { get; set; }
    public Container()
    {
        Items = new List<Widgets>();
    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Container c = new Container();
        c.Items.Add(new Widgets() { ID = 1, Name = "Sample Widget 1" });
        c.Items.Add(new Widgets() { ID = 2, Name = "Sample Widget 2" });

        foreach (Widgets item in c.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ID + " : " + item.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```