# ClassName<Type> or ClassName<Object> for abstract base class

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I'm relatively newbie to C# programming. I want to create **Abstract Base Class** that contains a few of `abstract`, and `virtual` methods.

By the following two examples, what are their differences of usage and which is more commonly used?

Example-1, use `Type` keyword.

```
public abstract class DecoratorBase<Type> : ValidatableBindableBase
{
    public virtual void SetFields(Type T) { }
    public virtual void SetFieldsBack(ref Type T) { }
}
```

Example-2, use `Object` keyword.

```
public abstract class DecoratorBase<Object> : ValidatableBindableBase
{
    public virtual void SetFields(Object T) { }
    public virtual void SetFieldsBack(ref Object T) { }
}
```

In my case, `Type` or `Object` will represent my business model **POCO** class.

Sorry, if this question sound so naive to you. Thanks.

Comment: Those are both absolutely *terrible* names for type parameters.  I think perhaps you don't understand what generics are (for).

Comment: Both are the same in this form. The problem is what @KirkWoll said. In the type parameter you just give a reference name so you can reference it later. Read this first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, **don't do that!**

It looks like you're a little confused about generics. When you define a generic abstract type (using `<` and `>` after the name), you're telling the compiler "I will give you some type, but I don't know which type just now. Use the name I'm giving you as a placeholder for the type later." The convention is to use the upper case `T`.

For example, the following defines a generic abstract class.

`public abstract class SomeClass<T> {}`

Later, when we create a derived class, we create it with a type:

`public class ConcreteClass : SomeClass<int> {}`

If we had methods declared in our abstract class that used the type `T`, our new `ConcreteClass` would replace references to `T` with `int`. So in your case, you should do:

```
public abstract class DecoratorBase<T> : ValidatableBindableBase
{
    public virtual void SetFields(T param) { }
    public virtual void SetFieldsBack(ref T param) { }
}
```

You can see here, `T` represents the unknown type as `T`, instead of naming the type `Type` and the parameter `T`. What you *were* doing is known as 'hiding', that is, When you use `Type` or `Object` in the way you were doing, it is assigning a new meaning to those words. You should absolutely avoid hiding in this way.

Now if you create a concrete class, say:

```
public class Decorator : DecoratorBase<Control>
{
    public override SetFields(Control param) {}
}
```

You have type safety: the parameter now *has* to be a `Control`, at least for this concrete implementation. You can define other implementations with different types, and inherit the same base methods.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359540/using-generics-in-abstract-classes) for a simple understanding of how to use generics.

Comment: To add to your answer. Type-params should sometimes have other names than just `T`. For instance, if you have a type-constraint on your type-parameter, then it's usually a good idea to try to infer that by name, for instance `TEntity` or `TUser`. This infers (without needing to further inspect the class) that there is a constraint, whereas `T` would imply that you can use *any type*. Just make sure to prefix it with `T`, for the same reasons you prefix interfaces with `I`.