# Is it possible to create a generic abstract parent class for different types?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I was curious if it was possible to create like a parent abstract class that I can define a specific set of methods in but have the children classes include different entity types? Code Example:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    public abstract void Add();

    public abstract void Delete();

    public abstract void Update();

    public abstract void Get();        
}
```

Maybe be able to do something like `public abstract List<'random type'> GetAll();`

But here i would want to override each method with specific parameters that are specific to each of its children:

```
public class CategoryService : BaseService
{
    public override void Add(){ }

    public override void Delete(){ }

    public override void Update(){ }

    public override void Get(){ }
}
```

However, in my child class, I would want my Get() method to return a specific List<"of Type"> (in this case Category). Furthermore, I might want to do `public override Add(int CategoryID)` instead of the inherited `Add` from `BaseService`.

Is this possible? Thoughts? Am I just crazy? Or am I trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be? I have about 10 different service types that I want to make sure get those generic methods from `BaseService`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you were going to have different parameters for `Add` in all the sub-classes, then what would you be gaining by having these defined in a base class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using generics in abstract classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359540/using-generics-in-abstract-classes)

Comment: `I might want to do public override Add(int CategoryID) instead of the inherited Add from BaseService.` Then why would you want to use `override` keyword at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this if I understand you correctly:

```
public abstract class BaseService<T>
{
    public abstract T Get();        
}
```

Then:

```
public class CategoryService : BaseService<Category>
{
    public override Category Get(){ ... }
}
```

You can't override methods and have a different signature in the override, but you could use a dictionary/hashtable or something more fancy to pass parameters into the `Add` method. Passing parameters in using a generic container would mean you are starting to use the *query* pattern where the parameters in the container determine the query (just for info :-)).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was going in this direction but wasn't 100% sure...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using generic type

```
public abstract List<T> GetAll<T>();
```

And return appropriate type in your child class

**Update**

@pw94 answer is also a good way to achieve this, but the only problem is you cannot have multiple type for different methods, only one type will work once you inherit the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class BaseService<T>
{
    public abstract void Add();

    public abstract List<T> Get();        
}
```

And implement:

```
public class CategoryService : BaseService<int>
{
    public override void Add(){ ... }

    public override List<int> Get(){ ... }
}
```